# How many ornamental fish can I catch in a day?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is there a limit to the number of ornamental fish one can catch in a day, except for the time spent fishing?

Comment: What do you mean "*except for the time spent fishing*"? That would have to be taken into account if there wasn't a limit, correct?

Comment: @Tacoタコス Yes, since I don't know if there is one. A natural limitation would always be that there are 24 hours in a day.

Comment: @Tacoタコス the user is asking if there is any hardcoded limit to the amount of fish you can catch in a day other than physical limitations due to the time you spend fishing. For comparison, there is a daily limit to the number of times you can interact with "Inspect" points (that probably no player will see unless they do serious farming), so it is possible that fishing works in a similar way.

Comment: @SPArcheon I understood; but if there is no hard coded limit, then the limit can be calculated. However, I think it’ll be hard to calculate because of how ornamental fish work.

Comment: @Tacoタコス calculating a "time based" limit would end up having no meaning, since you would have to make average assumptions that do not stand out in real life (average time to catch the fish, average number of fish/pond, average time lost switching ponds, average time lost switching time of day etc...), but... that is just personal opinion. I wouldn't see any attempt to calculate a time based limit if an hard coded lower one isn't found.

Comment: @SPArcheon I agree, I just asked for clarification purposes because I couldn’t find a hard limit quickly and others might be curious, so better to ask for clarification.